# WooCommerce: Get a key=>value array of a cart items variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-variations

**This is a self Q&A**

I need a way to neatly build a key=>value array of all the variations for an item in a cart. The available Woo functions all return a string.

Comment: Woo's documentation is so bad, and their functions so tied to HTML, that I plan on adding a lot of these Woo related Q&A as my firm tackles building Woo stores from scratch in the coming months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function takes a cart item, and returns a key=>value array.

Place it in `functions.php`

```
/*
 * Get a cart product/item's variation as a key=>value pair
 */
    function store_get_cart_product_variations($cart_item) {
        $variations = WC()->cart->get_item_data($cart_item, true); 

        // Explode and trim
        $parts = explode(PHP_EOL, $variations);
        $parts = array_filter($parts);

        // Build a key=>value pair, trim any extra whitespace
        $variations = array();
        foreach($parts as $part) {
            list($key, $value) = explode(':', $part);
            $variations[trim($key)] = trim($value);
        }

        return $variations;
    }
```

And then it can be used like this:

```
$cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
foreach ( $cart_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $variations = store_get_cart_product_variations($cart_item);        
    foreach($variations as $type => $value) {
        echo $type . ': ' . '<span class="value">' . $value .'</span>';
    }
}
```